# Which TLS protocol and ciphers are supported by SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

What is the latest TLS protocol (TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1) to be used in SQL Server 2005? Also what ciphers are supported?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. SQL Server 2005 is no longer supported. If you can add some context to your question explaining why you need to know about TLS support in SQL 2005, it might help us provide a more useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

(Note: extended support for SQL Server 2005 ended on April 12, 2016.)

From [this Microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server):

> Will SQL Server 2005 be supported for TLS 1.2?
>
> TLS 1.2 support is offered only for SQL Server 2008 and later versions.

From [this SQL Protocols blog entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2007/06/29/ssl-cipher-suites-used-with-sql-server/), for SQL 2000 and 2005:

> The currently recognised protocols are, from highest to lowest: TLS1.1, TLS1.0, SSL3.0, SSL2.0.

and

> [The] cipher suite to use is negotiated by SSL/TLS and depends upon the cipher suites supported by the OS on the client and the server.