# Is it possible to create a Linked Server from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2000

I am trying to create a Linked Server from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2016 R2. However, while creating I am getting the below error when trying to create Linked server from SQL Server 2000.

> TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
> host.
>
> Client unable to establish connection.

My SQL Server 2016 is on Windows Server 2016 and TLS 1.2 is only enabled. Do I need to enable TLS 1.0 and SSL 3.0 as well on SQL Server 2016 Windows Server ?

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/231064/170408. SQL 2000 can't use TLS 1.2, so yes, you'll need to enable TLS 1.1 or older on the destination server.